# How to add another wildcard variable to drupal mod_rewrite?

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I have a Drupal site that currently has some URL's like this...

http://www.example.com/exhibitions/2011/artist?p=works

I have Drupal's clean URL's turned on to create this url. The 'p' $_GET variable at the end is coming from my node template, which is used to show different fields from the node.

I would like to use mod_rewrite to change the url to this:

http://www.example.com/exhibitions/2011/artist/works

However im not sure how to adapt this to Drupal's current RewriteRules...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append this rule at the end of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(exhibitions/[^/]+/[^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1?p=$2 [L,NC,NE,QSA]
```